# How to pass value from Activity to Service

Tags: android, service

I tried to pass my value through a intent wich works fine if it is from Activity to another Activity. But this time is from a Activity to a Service. I thought this was the right approach? But i am getting an error Service class

My Activity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myLocation.disableCompass();
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationLoggerService.class);
    intent.putExtra("midllat", midllat);
    intent.putExtra("midlongi", midlongi);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

My Service Class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // Find my current location
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            2000, 0, this);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();
    towers = locationManager.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(towers);
    Toast.makeText(this, "The app is know running in the background",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    gm = new GoogleMaps();
```

I am getting a error in the getIntent() It can't find the method, is it because is in a service class? What to do?

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String test1 = intent.getStringExtra("midllat");
    String test2 = intent.getStringExtra("midlongi");

    midllat = Double.parseDouble(test1);
    midlongi = Double.parseDouble(test2);

}
```

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229370/how-to-pass-a-value-in-services?rq=1

Comment: I just said it? @alex .. It stands there 

I am getting a error in the getIntent() It can't find the method, is it because is in a service class? What to do?

Comment: @JafarKhQ... Just look at the code.. You cant use the getIntent() in the service class. What to do then? You posted questions doesn't help me..

Comment: I meant: what does the stack trace say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is certainly this:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

If you're trying to start a `Service`, you shouldn't be calling `startActivity`. Try [`startService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) instead.

Assuming you just forgot to change that in your question, the other problem as you pointed out is with `getIntent`. A `Service` doesn't have that method. That's an `Activity` method. Services are commonly associated with many intents, often simultaneously, so a `getIntent` method wouldn't really make sense. Read through the docs for `Service`, especially the [lifecycle section](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

You probably want to put your `Intent`-related code in [`onStartCommand`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: @Zaz if this answer sufficiently addresses your original question, then go ahead and accept it. As far as your crash goes, I'd recommend reading through the stack trace and making an attempt to understand the message and trying to fix it yourself. If you can't figure it out, then feel free to create a new question with details including that stack trace.